# Using $.Deferred() with nested ajax calls in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

I've spent far too many hours searching for similar questions and trying solutions, so I hope someone has a solution.

Basically, I would like to be notified when a function a() has completed. The problem is that the function contains an ajax call and a loop that calls b(), which again contains an ajax call.

UPDATED WITH FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hsyj7/1/

Like so:

```
// called by main()
function a() {
  return $.ajax("http://url1").pipe(function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      console.log('a called');
      b();
    }
  });
}

// called by a()
function b() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $.ajax("http://url2", function(data){
      // do something
      console.log('b called');
    }
  }
}

function main(){
  $.when(a()).done(function(){
    console.log('all completed');
  });
}
```

What I would like to see then is, possibly with both calls to a() at the top:

```
a called
b called
b called
a called
b called
b called
all completed
```

Instead I get

```
a called
all completed
b called
b called
```

Or some variant thereof.

I am aware that the above code is missing defer functionality in both the loop and in b(). 
In some of the variants I have tried, the done() handler in main() is never called.

Any one know how to do this?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is some kind of counter which decrements as the AJAX calls return and then fires a `complete` event when it reaches `0`. I'm not posting that as an answer as there's got to be something more elegant :)

Comment: Here's a fiddle of the question: http://jsfiddle.net/pxVAE/

Comment: I had a similar question, that wasn't quite resolved. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273437/jquery-deferred-object-with-nested-ajax-calls

Comment: Do you also want to execute `b()` in sequence or in parallel? I.e. do you want to wait for `b` to finish before you call it a second time?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yeah, using `Deferred` is the way to do that:

```
function a() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax("http://url1").done(function(data){
        var requests = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
             requests.push(b());
        }

        $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() { def.resolve(); });
    });

    return def.promise();
}

// called by a()
function b() {
    var def = $.Deferred(),
        requests = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        requests.push($.ajax("http://url2").done(function(data){
            // do something
            console.log('b called');
        });
    }

    $.when.apply($, requests).then(function() { def.resolve(); });

    return def.promise();
}

function main(){
    $.when(a()).done(function(){
        console.log('all completed');
    });
}
```

//EDIT: Replaced `.pipe` with `.done`.

Comment: I'd +1, but I'm out of votes. Just FMI, what's being achieved by using `pipe()` in `a()` (or in this case is it just synonymous with using `then()`?)

Comment: @Matt In this piece of code? Absolutely nothing. I assume it is a snippet from larger piece of code.

Comment: Thanks @freakish, that works! My confusion was when to use resolve() and promise() in the loops.

Comment: -1 for not handling errors. Also, why do you use the `pipe` method when you don't utilize it?

Comment: @Bergi Am I supposed to write all of the code for OP? I've simply shown him how to achieve what he wants.

Comment: No, but it would help if the bad practise of constructing `$.Deferred`s does not spread :-)

Comment: @Bergi I agree ( I'll update the question once I have enough time to recall what was it even about :D ). However since it does answer the question I don't think it deserves -1.

Comment: I think (high-voted) bad-practise answers are a hazard (to the >1k viewers), so I pressed "*answer is not useful*". I'm looking forward to see it corrected!

Comment: @Bergi I've fixed it. It should be ok now.

Comment: Usage of `pipe` was not the problem - it would've been the solution actually. The problem is manually constructing and resolving deferreds. You might want to have a look a my answer below.

Comment: @Bergi Then we completely disagree. You've moved a big part of function `a()` outside of it. What if it is called somewhere else directly? I can't agree to such refactoring. We should not modify the original code more then necessary.

Comment: Sure - check my update. This triviality of the change is the reason to use `then` for composing asynchronous actions.

Comment: @Bergi I see, it seems to be fine now (there are still many things for me to learn about jQuery, indeed). However I disagree that using deferreds directly is a problem. Longer? Yes. Incorrect? No. It's just another solution to the problem. I'll leave the answer as it is. People can use your solution, I don't mind. I'll even upvote it.

Comment: It's an error-prone design. People forget to reject the deferreds when they would need - just like you have. Using `then` automatically takes care of that.

Comment: @Bergi I didn't forget about it - I just didn't care. I agree that it is error-prone but that doesn't mean that it is incorrect. Your solution might be better, but it doesn't mean that mine is wrong.

Comment: @freakish , with reference to your answer I tried a sample to execute a deferred function in loop. However the result is not working as expected.  Refer - https://jsfiddle.net/fewtalks/nvbp26sx/1/. This prints output as  {{ processed test1 item 0;
 processed test1 item 1;
processed test item 0;
 processed test item 1;
completed}} . However I expect the output as {{ processed test1 item0 processed test item0; processed test1 item1; processed test item0}}. Why the deferred test function is not executing after test1 is completed.

Comment: @fewtalks Post this as a new question (with full code copied there) and we'll have a look at it. It's hard to read from your comment what is the expected output.

Comment: @freakish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468428/jquery-deferred-in-each-loop-with-ajax-callback

Answer (score 2):

You could use an *Array* which is located in a higher context to push *Promise / Deferred* objects into. Then you could then use `jQuery.when` alongside `Function.prototype.apply` to pass all entries as arguments.

```
(function() {
    var promises = [ ],
        when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( jQuery.when, null );

    function a() {
         promises.push($.ajax("http://url1").pipe(function(data){
             for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                 console.log('a called');
                 b();
             }
         }));

         return promises;
    }

    function b() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            promises.push($.ajax("http://url2", function(data) {
                // do something
                console.log('b called');
            }));
        }
    }

    function main() {
        promises = [ ];

        when( a() ).done(function(){
            console.log('all completed');
        });
    }
}());
```

Comment: -1: Multiple calls to `a` will cause a memory leak, because `promises` is a "global" list.

Comment: @freakish: its not a global list. OP didn't say anything about multiple calls. Even if that was the case, it would only push more objects into the *Array* which definitely is not a *memory leak*. He would just need to `re-initialize` the *Array*. -1 for that? Are you joking ?

Comment: That's why I wrote *global* in quation marks. Global from `a` and `b` point of view. OP clearly gave example of `a` being called twice. The memory leak is there, because you only push to `promises`.

Comment: @freakish: you better google for the definition of a *memory leak* bro, pushing data into an array is just not that. But again, resetting that to an empty *Array* is open for everyone. Again, this is not a downvote. Are you joking..

Comment: Then why didn't you include resetting in your solution? The code leaks memory when called multiple times. True or false? I don't understand why are you constantly trying to make fun of me. Write your solution properly, then I will upvote.

Comment: @freakish: Actually, `a()` is only called once in the OP's example. And since all the functions in jAndy's solution are inside a function expression, none of them can actually called ;) That's more worth to be pointed out :)

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, you're right. Sorry, I thought that `console.log` is before loop. Fair enough, I'll upvote now.

Comment: @freakish: I don't want a flamewar. But you should seriously re-think your behavior. Your wording in this *ECMAcript context* is pretty questionable (quotation or not and about memory leaks) + the fact that its not stated the function is getting called more than once.

Comment: @jAndy Re-think my behavior? I'm very patient and polite. I'm not your "bro" and I like to use quation marks ( which is not difficult to understand, seriously ) and I don't make fun of other people. Maybe you should re-think your behavior? Now I've made a mistake and I apologize.

Comment: @FelixKling True, however we all know, that this is just a snippet and perhaps this is bound to some event. Anyway potentially it can lead to memory leak.

Comment: @jAndy I think you could even scope and return `promises` inside both of `a()` and `b()`, to get rid of *context state* altogether

Comment: @freakish: Exactly, it's just a snippet... no need to rumble too much about it... ease up everyone, it's Christmas time :)

Comment: @freakish: I didn't make any fun of you, I was just shocked that I seriously got a downvote, with that reason. The reason wasn't even correct or true (by definition), so that is what I call a wrong behavior on this site.

Comment: @FelixKling: what do you mean with *none of them can actually called* ? Code works as expected.

Comment: Where are you calling `main()`?

Comment: @FelixKling: where does the OP call it ?

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to point out that none of the functions `a`, `b` and `main` are accessible from outside the whole code block. So assuming OP calls `main` *somewhere*, it could not be found with your code.

Comment: @jAndy Hehe, so maybe we should be very strict and *by definition* ( whatever that means ) answer that the code works correct, because it is not called anywhere. Question closed. Because OP didn't state it. You are so stubborn, while everyone knows that the code you've shown us potentially leads to memory leak. Also it can be easily fixed, so I don't understand this entire attack. And stop offending me all the time. Not correct? Not true? B***ch, please.

Comment: @freakish: I truly believe that I'm pretty open minded and not stubborn. But you just "assume" things and based on that, predict *memory leaks* (which still are no memory leaks, still, by definition) and dangerously fool around with words like *global* which are generally used in a whole different way. That plus of course the downvote for this questionable overall behavior. What did you expect me to do ? Say thank you ?

Comment: @jAndy Is it that difficult to assume it? Is it so unlikely to happen? You did assume that `main` is called somewhere, right ( otherwise the code works **by definition** )? So I assumed that it is possibly called multiple times. How is it different? And do you have to be so stubborn about "global" word, you grammar freak? Not to mention that we should also teach good practices and what you've shown us is not even close. You don't have to say anything, just fix your solution. OK, that's it for me. I won't argue anymore, as Felix stated is is Christmas time after all. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @freakish: its not difficult, but quite leaning far out of the window. It's one thing to expect that a code gets executed once (otherwise there is no error or questions) but a different story to predict or assume unknown application logic. And you call me stubborn ;) Beeing picky on your *global* expression is still correct imho. It wouldn't on any other tag, but this question is tagged with *javascript*. Merry xmas.

Comment: @jAndy OMG, fair enough, I apologize for misusing "global" word. :) I won't apologize for calling you stubborn, though. :) Merry Christmas!

Comment: -1. The `promises.push` in `b()` is too late, `$.when()` will not account for them.

Answer (score 2):

The question might be old, but since there's no correct solution yet I'll put an answer here. It properly chains the promises by using [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (previsouly been `.pipe`) to achieve the requested result:

```
function a() {
  return $.ajax("http://url1").done(function(data){
    console.log('a called');
  }).then(function(){
    return $.when(b(), b()); // no loop for simplicity
  });
}
function b() {
  return $.ajax("http://url2").done(function(data){
    console.log('b called');
  });
}

function main(){
  a().done(function(){
    console.log('all completed');
  }, function() {
    console.log('an error occured!');
  });
}
```

Depending on which result data should be available where the nesting/structure might be changed, but the overall ordering is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can be fixed with callbacks, but a fiddle would have really helped me check for you.

```
 // called by main()
 function a(callback) {
   //set this to the number of loops that is going to happen
   var number = 2;
   return $.ajax("http://url1", function(data){
     console.log('a called');
     for (var i = 0; i < number ; i++) {
       b();
       if(number===i){
           callback();
       }
     }
   }
 }

 function main(){
    a(function(){
       //Function or code you want to run on completion.. 
    });
 }
```

Forgive me if this doesn't work, but i think its the right direction.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pxVAE/1/. Doesn't quite work, might be in my transcribing...