# Deferred Async Tasks with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I'm new to deferred classes in JavaScript and would like to implement a function which will loop through forms and submit them one by one.

Looks like Deferred classes are the way to accomplish this.

I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951699/442580), but for some reason my implementation starts, waits 3 seconds and completes. I want it to show a different form name every 3 seconds until it's done with all the forms then complete.

What am I doing wrong? [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v6cgak1u/1/)

```js
function syncAll() {
        
  var promises = [];
  var forms = [
    {'name':'form 1'},
    {'name':'form 2'},
    {'name':'form 3'}, 
    {'name':'form 4'}];

  $.each(forms, function (index, value) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#output").html("Syncing: " + value.name);
      def.resolve({ 'message': 'finito!' });
    }, 3000);
    promises.push(def);

  });

  return $.when.apply(undefined, promises).promise();
}
    
    
    $.when(syncAll()).done(function(response){
        $("#output").html(response.message);
    });
    /*
    syncAll().done(function (response) {
      $("#output").html(response.message);
    }));
    */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">Start</div>
```

Comment: `$.when` applies promises *in parallel* and awaits them all finishing. All your forms are submitting at the same time. You want to chain them *in sequence* with `.then()`

Comment: Having your own delay() function, that returns a timer promise, is also useful to keep your code clean.

Comment: @GoneCoding - So how would I chain the sequence if it's a loop calling the same function? say `submitForm`.

Comment: Added answer below to demonstrate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/v6cgak1u/2/

This uses a `promise = promise.then(functionReturningNextPromise)` pattern:

```
function syncAll() {
    var promise = $.when();  // Start with a resolved promise.
    var forms = [
      {'name':'form 1'},
      {'name':'form 2'},
      {'name':'form 3'}, 
      {'name':'form 4'}];

    $.each(forms, function (index, value) {
        promise = promise.then(function(){
            var def = $.Deferred();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#output").html("Syncing: " + value.name);
                def.resolve({ 'message': 'finito!' });
            }, 3000);
            return def.promise();
        });
    });
    return promise;
}


$.when(syncAll()).done(function(response){
    $("#output").html(response.message);
});
```

This could be improved a bit by replacing the setTimeout and having a timed promise method instead that also chains together (still implemented using setTimeout).

Note that `new` is not required on `$.Deferred()`

**EDIT** :

Features of javascript and jQuery can be exploited to make the code slightly more concise :

```
function syncAll() {
    var forms = [
        {'name':'form 1'},
        {'name':'form 2'},
        {'name':'form 3'}, 
        {'name':'form 4'}
    ];
    return forms.reduce(function(promise, value) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return $("#output").delay(1000).html("Syncing: " + value.name).promise();
        });
    }, $.when()).then(function() {
        return {'message': 'finito!'};
    });
}

syncAll().then(function(response) {
    $("#output").html(response.message);
});
```

This is essentially the same paradigm as above but exploits :

- ['array.reduce()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build the promise chain from the `forms` array.
- jQuery's [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) instead of `setTimeout()`, to implement delay.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, I'll take some time to absorb this, then come back and mark your answer as correct. Genius.

Comment: @capdragon, you can achieve the same end by exploiting features of javascript and jQuery **[like this](https://jsfiddle.net/u75guwv3/)**.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Suggest you post that as an answer with detailed explanation. I did not shorten my own example any further as it would become too complicated to explain.

Comment: @GoneCoding, I don't want to compete with your answer. If I find time I'll add to the bottom of yours if that's OK?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Be my guest