# Chaining a promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I check if a post exists in table. If it does not, I insert it. So I need to make two async calls. Can I do this flat with promises?

```
var insertOrUpdateBuilding = (callback)=>{
    // Check if building exists
    db('buildings')
      .where({externalId: buildingId})
      .then(function(rows){
        // Building exist, do nothing
        if(rows){
          callback ();
        }
        // Building does not exist. Insert it
        if(!rows){
          return db('buildings').insert({externalId: buildingId, name: req.body.name})
        }
      })
      .then(function(promise){

      })
      .catch(function(err){
        callback({message: 'Error looking up building', err: err})
      })
  };
```

I'm stuck. How do I proceed?

Comment: Generally you don't mix promises and callbacks. What's the database library you are using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273437/jquery-deferred-object-with-nested-ajax-calls

Comment: @SunilBN The OP clearly is not using jQuery deferred objects.

Comment: maybe it would be clearer to have `insertOrUpdateBuilding` return a `Promise`.

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises are sticky, once you start using them, every involved function will  have to accept and return promises as well. In your example, if `db()` is promised, then `insertOrUpdateBuilding` should return a promise too, that is, `db(...)` with some `then`s attached to it

```
var insertOrUpdateBuilding = () => db('buildings')
    .where({externalId: buildingId})
    .then(rows => rows ||
        db('buildings').insert({externalId: buildingId, name: req.body.name}))
    ;
```

and whoever calls `insertOrUpdateBuilding` should be promised as well:

```
  insertOrUpdateBuilding().then(okay).catch(error!)
```

Note that it generally doesn't make sense to `catch` errors in a lower-level function (except for logging/debugging purposes). Let the error propagate to the upper level where you can handle it in a sensible way, e.g. inform the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ES7 async/await.

```
var async insertOrUpdateBuilding = (callback) => {
    try {
        // Check if building exists
        let rows = await db('buildings')
          .where({externalId: buildingId});
        // Building exist, do nothing
        if (rows){
          callback();
        }
        // Building does not exist. Insert it
        if (!rows) {
          let row = await db('buildings').insert({
            externalId: buildingId, 
            name: req.body.name
          });
          callback();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        callback({message: 'Error looking up building', err: e});
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the question.  The question was about promises, async/await might not be available.

Comment: @DavinTryon Thanks for the comment. I just added it. First skipped it to not mess up the code principle.